# Convert wav file from WAV_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE to WAV_FORMAT_PCM

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-conversion, wav

I have a 16-bit 44.1kHz wav file in `WAV_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` format. What is a simple and efficient way to convert it to `WAV_FORMAT_PCM` on the command-line?

ffmpeg solutions preferred, but I'm also open to using other tools.

In case it helps, [here's a sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9avRO8DvfSRinDNwFv6YKZsnLK1noHi/view?usp=sharing).

Also, I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425970/force-ffmpeg-to-output-wav-format-pcm), but the accepted answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You may get the entire list of audio codecs by executing `ffmpeg -encoders` (there are about 30 codecs with name starting with `pcm_`). Can you tell which codec applies `WAV_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` and which codec applies `WAV_FORMAT_PCM`?

Comment: @Rotem My `WAV_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` (WFE) file is `pcm_s16le`, but I also have a normal `WAV_FORMAT_PCM` (WFP) files that is pcm_s16le. Specifying the encoding as `pcm_s16le` does not make the conversion happen.

In general, WFE is required for 24-bit and 32-bit audio, but not 16-bit. So if I specify `pcm_s24le`, then I can get ffmpeg to output a WFE file no matter what. But WFE essentially supports everything WFP does, plus more. So it's hard to get ffmpeg to convert it back into WFP once the input is in WFE. There's no encoding I know of that forces WFP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SO post you linked sort of answered your question, but the code it quoted is too old.

`ffmpeg` creates either `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` or `WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE` depending on the "spec" of the input audio. Essentially there's no way to tell it which to create.

It does create `WAVE_FORMAT_PCM` for 16-bit 44.1KHz mono/stereo input, but with [modern ffmpeg (3.2 or later)](https://github.com/tomty89/FFmpeg/commit/fe8959bbece4d86a1872b813c25c2682dcd5ef42), it also checks the channel layout (that is either supplied by the input file, or, overridden by the user at runtime with `-channel_layout`).

I can't tell anything about your "other" files, but the "problem" with the sample file you supplied is that it has a channel layout and the layout is NOT [AV_CH_LAYOUT_MONO](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n5.1/libavutil/channel_layout.h#L204):

```
$ ffprobe -hide_banner tiny.wav 
Input #0, wav, from 'tiny.wav':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Paul and M solo
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, bitrate: 710 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s16, 705 kb/s
```

(Note the `(FR)` that follows `1 channels`)

And the solution is to override the layout:

```
$ ffmpeg -i tiny.wav -c copy tiny2.wav -channel_layout mono -c copy tiny3.wav &> /dev/null 
$ ffprobe -hide_banner tiny2.wav 
Input #0, wav, from 'tiny2.wav':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Paul and M solo
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, bitrate: 710 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels (FR), s16, 705 kb/s
$ ffprobe -hide_banner tiny3.wav 
Input #0, wav, from 'tiny3.wav':
  Metadata:
    artist          : Paul and M solo
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.20, bitrate: 709 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
$ du -b tiny*
17766   tiny2.wav
17742   tiny3.wav
17766   tiny.wav
```

(The 2-byte `cbSize` field, plus the extra (meta)data `cbSize` refers to, which is at least 22 bytes, equals to 24 bytes. The 2-byte `wBitsPerSample` is NOT omitted as `ffmpeg` follows [`PCMWAVEFORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/ns-mmeapi-pcmwaveformat) instead of [`WAVEFORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmreg/ns-mmreg-waveformat) when it does not follow [`WAVEFORMATEX`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd757713(v=vs.85)).)